# Fallback for CDN in angular2

Tags: angular, cdn

I want to refer some reference links from CDN, but also wanted to have the fallback mechanism where-in if the cdn links fails for some reason, it should automatically refer to the local version. 
I searched in the net but found answers in Jquery, any ideas how do i handle it in angular2?

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: CDN's guarantee almost 100% availability. They are distributed, I think worrying about that is unnecessary.

Comment: @Eduardo, I agree about the availability, but there could be other issues like firewall or secured client network because of which the CDN may not be able to download. Want to know how to handle it in those scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I needed the same thing, but only for the CSS part, so I came up with the following.

I added  on the top line of `app.component.html`

```js
<span class="bs hidden"></span>
```

In `AppComponent` class I added the `ngAfterViewInit` function and a helper `_getElementStyle` function like this:

```js
import { Component, AfterViewInit, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
}) 
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private _renderer: Renderer) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    let bs = this._renderer.selectRootElement('.bs.hidden');
    if (this._getElementStyle(bs, 'display') !== 'none') {
      let link = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('link')).find((link: any) => {
        return link.rel && link.rel === 'stylesheet' &&
          link.href && link.href.indexOf('bootstrap') !== -1;
      });

      if (link) {
        link.href = 'assets/bootstrap.min.css';
        link.removeAttribute('integrity');
        link.removeAttribute('crossorigin');
      }
    }

    bs.remove();
  }

  private _getElementStyle(elem: any, declarationName: string): string {

    if (typeof elem === 'string') {
      declarationName = elem;
      elem = this;
    }

    // Element does not exist.
    if (!elem || typeof elem !== 'object') {
      return undefined;
    }

    let win: Window = window || document.defaultView;
    let style: CSSStyleDeclaration | any;

    style = win.getComputedStyle /* Modern browsers */
      ? win.getComputedStyle(elem)
      : elem.currentStyle /* IE 8- */
        ? elem.currentStyle
        : elem.style; /* Ancient browsers */

    declarationName = win.getComputedStyle
      ? declarationName.toLowerCase()
      : elem.currentStyle
        ? declarationName.replace(/\-(\w)/g, (str, letter) => {
          return letter.toUpperCase();
        })
        : declarationName;

    return style[declarationName];
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.